# How to define a toolbar that persist over a storyboard based ios application?

Tags: ios, storyboard, toolbar

I'm developing an ios app based on a storyboard.

Anyone knows how can I define a toolbar that will exist over the entire application?

I would like to use the graphical editor to design it.

My first attempt was to design the toolbar over the navigation controller (the first one on the storyboard), and i can see the toolbar over other views but without bar buttons.. (bar buttons that i have designed on the toolbar of my navigation controller)?!

Comment: I am not sure your can design a tool bar in your storyboard and have that used over your entire app easily. However, you might want to take a look at UIAppearance, if you are looking to theme the toolbar then you can change background, tints etc and it will be applied to all of the toolbars (or whatever ui component you are using) in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbars can be populated via a NSArray. You could just have a toolbar for each view and pass the array when segue is called. Just as you pass anything else.